# How can I add an existing character article to my GM's Screen in World Anvil?

Tags: tools, world-anvil

I have a large number of characters described in character articles in [World Anvil](https://www.worldanvil.com/).  I'd like to put them on my StoryTeller's screen for easy access during games.  I see an option to create a new NPC, but don't see an option to add an existing character.

How can I add a character article to my Story Teller's Screen as an NPC?

[image: Screenshot of World Anvil Supporting Cast Screen showing the Add an NPC button]

Comment: While it’s stylized without a space in their trade dress, their website includes the space in plain text as “World Anvil”, so I’ve created the tag with a hyphen and added the space in your post and title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only PCs and NPCs can be added to the DSTS (the Storyteller screen)—but you can connect an NPC to an existing character article:

1. Create a new NPC from the interface you're showing in the screenshot
2. Fill in the relevant details but don't click the save button yet.
3. Click on "Additional details" and use the "Linked character article" drop-down to connect it to an article you're already created.
4. Click the save button.

You'll now be able to add the character to parties, which will make it available on the party manager (left sidebar of the DSTS).

---

That said, you have access to your entire library of articles from within the DSTS. Just use the search bar at the top and look up the character name. If you think you'll reference it frequently, you can add it to the library for quick access (so you only have to click it rather than looking it up every time).